# LAN hardware / setup

Tags: networking

me and my buddies play lan in an office afterhours and use their established infrastructure ...ie, no idea what kind of cables, routers, hubs, switches, firewals are behind the walls...

we play out of two or three rooms, where we plug an old 10/100 switch into the wall and distribute among the users in that room. The "server" is either someone's laptop or the office computer of the dude that works there.

either the "work comp" or "laptop" is generally decent specs with 10/100/1000 e-cards

we currently play COD4:MW and get pings of around 50-70, sometimes spike to even higher.

my suggestion to the guys was to get a new switch (or two) and run our own cable from the "work comp" into the rooms where we play (bout 50 feet)

my question is this:

do we get one big switch and have cables everywhere.. (25-30 feet from adjecent rooms)

or get two or three switches (one for each room) and simply daisy chain them together.

assuming that either all the switches are gigabit unamanaged, or if 10/100 then with a gigabit uplink port (but why bother?)

how much latency would we be losing by doing the daisy chain route? if any? Does it matter?

we're not gonna be connecting to the internet or doing datatransfers, just straight up gaming.

Comment: to set stuff up you 'kind of' need to know what transmission medium, routers, hubs and switches you are using

Comment: 10-12 laptops
1 game
proposed switch: Cisco SG100-8 (if using 8s) and SG100-24 if we go with just 1.
cables will be CAT6 i guess?

that's about it, really.

Answer (score 1):

Technically each switch adds some latency, but based on your described scenario, you wouldn't notice the difference if you chained 3 (decent) switches or ran each device directly to one (decent) switch.

Comment: +1. The entire problem is not quite a problem to bother about it, so one decent modern switch will handle load.

Comment: thank you.

i would prefer though to daisy chain because that means less cables. (smaller cables, since i'll only have one 25' conencting the two rooms and then everyone can work of 2-3')

Cuz if i do a single switch then there will be this thick, 25-30' snake of 6 cables that i'll need to lug around. 

so i wanted to know if i'm missing out on latency, if at all

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a single switch and connect all of the computers to it, including the computer acting as the game server.
2. Do not connect this switch to the existing network infrastructure.
3. Forget about CAT6 cables. Just get CAT5e cables. There's no advantage to using CAT6 cables and GbE will happily run over CAT5e.

Comment: Using multiple switches and/or connecting to the existing production network increases the chances of you inadvertently creating a switch loop, which would have a negative impact on your game network and/or the production network.

Answer (score 0):

Get 1 switch for each room and connect them together. You'd likely see more issues from having a dozen long cables strewn about everywhere. The latency added by multiple switches in series would be negligible (sub-millisecond).